# Directory based virtual RAID1

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, raid-1

## The problem:

I have video files for a project that require editing. Those files are larger than usual, therefore disk speed became an important obstacle during my work.

## The Idea:

I know I could setup RAID or get SSD, but that is unreal for me at the moment. I however have two main drives in my PC (aside from my system SSD). Both those drives have enough free space to hold the files I have to work with.

Is there a way I could create something like two 500 GB folders, one on drive A and one on drive B and then mirror those folders and let them act as one? In sort of RAID1 fashion. The idea is that my data would be on both drives, so reading speed would be increased by using two physical lanes. At the same time, I would not have to commit both entire drives for RAID1.

**So, is this even possible? How? If yes, is there any significant increase in performance?**

Comment: Would you not be better off looking for a RAID0 striping solution ?  RAID1 provides data reliability, but RAID0 can provide greater speed (by being able to split up writes rather then do 2 disk writes for every actual write). [  Sorry, I can't provide an answer for you - I only do Linux ]

Comment: What has your research effort shown using Google? Questions on SU are expected to show some research effort on your part and should be included in your question.